# Javascript Intellisense unusable

Tags: javascript, telerik, intellisense

I have an external javascript file that references Telerik, jQuery and my own utilities project.

I have tried all types of things but I have yet to see Intellisense made available for any of the referenced scripts.

Currently I have something like this at the top of my page

```
/// <reference name="MyUtilities.ClientScripts.jquery-1.4.2.vsdoc.js" assembly="MyUtilities" />
/// <reference name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.Core.js" assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" />
/// <reference name="MyUtilities.ClientScripts.myUtilities.js" assembly="MyUtilities"/>
```

Notice that i have tried adding jQuery as an embedded resource, rather than pulling it down through a CDN. In either case, I still haven't seen any Intellisense.

In the Output window I *sometimes* see the error message: "JScript IntelliSense timed out. Results may be limited". There are also millions of error messages for the Telerik js file.

I've tried refreshing Intellisense with Ctrl-Shift-J and also tried restarting the browser.

Javascript Intellisense in Visual Studio 2010 seems to be a total mess for all but the most basic examples. Has any ever got some joy from this sort of scenario?

Comment: I don't know, but if there are "millions of error messages for the Telerik js file" then Visual Studio probably gave up trying to parse it for intellisense purposes. Does the intellisense work for the others if you (temporarily) remove that file?

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but just in case.

I think that you should try adding the references you are correctly trying to add to a separate file, named `_references.js`, that you should place in the Script folder.

More about this [at this blog page](http://gurustop.net/blog/2012/03/03/javascript-js-intellisense-auto_complete-in-visual-studio-11-beta-the-web-_references-js-file/)

Answer (score 1):

I followed the instructions [here](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/introduction-jquery-intellisense.html) and had intellisense working partially.

Also, as eddo said, use an _reference.js file. Here's how mine looks:

```
/// <reference path="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.0.3-vsdoc.js" />
/// <reference path="globalize.js" />
/// <reference path="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/globalize/0.1.1/globalize.js" />
/// <reference path="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-3.0.0.debug.js" />
/// <reference path="MicrosoftAjax.debug.js" />
/// <reference assembly="Telerik.Web.UI, Version=2013.3.1114.45, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4" name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.Core.js" />
/// <reference assembly="Telerik.Web.UI, Version=2013.3.1114.45, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4" name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQuery.js" />
/// <reference assembly="Telerik.Web.UI, Version=2013.3.1114.45, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4" name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQueryInclude.js" />
```

I have opened a forum thread about this issue [here](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/general-discussions/visual-studio-javascript-intellisense-with-rad-controls.aspx) if you want to follow.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but just in case. I actually removed my _references file to get my intellisense back.

It seems if there is an error in it then it will completely disables all your js intellisense - although I never manually touched that file.